# Remove particular entries from ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to remove particular entries just from the legend,
while keeping them on the actual plot?

In particular, I have a dodged `geom_bar` where I wanted to change the colours of the last entry as they show a `mean` over the previous bars. To do this, I've created a new groups, called `_A` and `_B`.

However, in the legend I want to show just the entries for `A` and `B`, omitting the special groups I've created.
Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

If I set their labels to an empty string, the coloured box will still appear, without any text next to it.

Cheers,
Paschalis

Comment: Maybe the solution from this question will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735675/creating-a-custom-legend-with-a-subset-of-data-ggplot

Comment: This might be useful as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-legend-entries-for-some-factors-levels

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I've seen the solution. It *dont* have to create a duplicate variable though. I just have to use breaks for `scale_fill_manual`